# Make a edittext box display on a textview?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I am trying to make an android app for my local fence painting business and I simply want it to calculate quotes and payments. My problem is figuring out how to get a simple input box for the square feet of the fence (edittext) with the help of a button to display a that input to a textview. Will you help me?

Also if there is a different way to do this I would love to hear it.
Thank you!

Comment: Show your code, what you ask seems to be quite simple, you can set the text you want on a `TextView` by using the function `setText` on it. Example: `yourTextView.setText(yourEditText.getText());`

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is figuring out how to get a simple input box for the
>   square feet of the fence (edittext) with the help of a button to
>   display a that input to a textview.

Pretty simple. Create a `TextView`, a `Button` and an `EditText` object:

```
TextView txtView;
Button btn;
EditText edtText;
```

Initialize them:

```
txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id...);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id...);
edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id...);
```

This is how you get the input of the `EditText` by clicking the `Button` and set the input to the `TextView`:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         String inputText = edtText.getText().toString(); // Get the input
         txtView.setText(inputText); // Set the text to the TextView
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response however the code fills my computer with errors. I cant get the "setOnClickListener or the onClick method to not have errors. Please help.